# Connecting to Redis running in Docker from host

Tags: docker, redis

I'm running RedisEdge in Docker hosted on Windows 10. The Docker-Compose YAML looks like this:

```
services:
  redisedge:
    build: ./redisedge
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

I can connect to RedisEdge from Python services running in Docker at redis://redisedge:6379. I can access it from Grafana running in Docker at host.docker.internal:6379. I can access it from RedisInsight running on host at host.docker.internal:6379. But when I try to access it from a Python file running locally on either of the addresses above, I get this error: "Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
Error 11001 connecting to redisedge:6379. getaddrinfo failed."

Do I need to run RedisEdge differently?

Comment: What about just `localhost:6379`? If the Python file is running on the host, it just needs the host-mapped port. This is `6379` because you expose that port on the host in the Compose file (`[HOST-PORT]:[CONTAINER-PORT]`).

Comment: Not ```http://localhost:6379```?

Comment: Redis uses its own custom TCP-based protocol, not HTTP.

Comment: Are you confirming that doesn't work? Alternatively, to avoid resolving `localhost`, you could try `127.0.0.1`. I don't understand why that wouldn't work. If you're on Linux, please also try `ss --tcp --listening --processes | grep 6379`

Comment: Aha! @david-maze has it.

Comment: Got it, thank you!