# Cannot connect to redis in docker and django

Tags: django, docker

I have run a redis container using this command: `docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis`.

and I have run my Django app using this command: `docker run -it -p 8000:8000 voucher`.

and my connection redis url is `redis://redis:6379/1`.

But i cannot seem to connect to redis here is my error:
`redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known.`

**PS:** I'm not using `docker-compose`

Comment: why you don't use docker-compose. its really easy to setup

Comment: I wanted to know both sides. @S.Sachith

Comment: oh, thats nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have fix that by changing my redis connection url to
> redis://172.17.0.2:6379/1. But why is that ? How can I use container
> names instead of IPs?

This is your host IP. You have a few ways to solve your problem.

1 - Use the hardcoded IP as you did.

2 - Use docker link to connect applications like:

```
docker run --name my-redis-application --link my-redis-container:redis -d centos
```

3 - You can create a redis.conf with the follow content:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

and use it in the startup like:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/usr/local/etc/redis/ --name redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

4 - You can use docker-compose to link then better, like in #2.

Answer (score 2):

Both Container have to be in the same `Docker network` to be able to communicate via the Container names.

```
docker run -d --name redis --network your-network -p 6379:6379 redis

docker run -it --network your-network -p 8000:8000 voucher
```

Comment: correct, but maybe you could mention that `your-network` has to be created with `docker network create ...` before it can be referenced (for completeness)

Comment: connected them to bridge network but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

*I think the better option is docker-compose. if you like to use docker-compose here is the answer.*

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services :
  redis:
    image : redis
    container_name : redis
    restart : unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 6379:6379 
  voucher:
    image : voucher
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

now you can connect to Redis using the service name "redis".

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined redis info in .env file?
That could lead to connection error too.

*/.env*

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=yourpassword/blank
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: yeah I have defined them in a `.env` file but that was not the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that by changing my redis connection url to `redis://172.17.0.2:6379/1`.
But why is that ?
How can I use container names instead of IPs?

Comment: How where you using the container name?

Comment: my container name was `redis` and my connection url was `redis://redis:6379/1`

Comment: In order to use the DNS of docker your need to put the containers in the [default bridge network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421292/connecting-to-redis-running-in-docker-from-host). Did you check that?